# C# web api facebook and google + OWIN authentication access token

Tags: c#, facebook, authentication, owin

So, I managed to get UserDetails from google and facebook tokens. I got userId, name, email, etc... My question is, how to generate OWIN authentication access token from these details.

When registering normal user, I would just type username and password and it would generate token, but, when dealing with google+ and facebook logins, how to handle that?

Comment: I strongly recommend reading these questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16836467/how-to-get-google-plus-access-token-in-windows-application-c-net http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906486/how-to-get-an-access-token-using-c-sharp-sdk

Comment: Managed to do that, now I need access token for my Web application.